# Azure secured WebAPI with Azure AD calling on premises services (SharePoint, SQL)

Tags: azure, sharepoint, asp.net-web-api2, office365, azure-active-directory

I’ve been through this excellent series from [Kirk Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3525788/kirk-evans-msft):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2015/03/27/the-api-economy-consuming-our-web-api-from-a-single-page-app.aspx

but I need go a step further. I need same architecture he’s drawn in the article: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-25-31-metablogapi/4064.image_5F00_6A334CB5.png

but now, the Custom WebAPI in Azure, needs to call another API in an On Premises infrastructure, considering this on premises API would need to get information from SharePoint On premises “on behalf” of the user (and surely from other origins like SQL Servers or other internal services).

I’m assuming both Active directories (Azure AD and on premises AD) are federated.

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: have you found a solution for that setup?

Comment: haven't yet. I'm pretty sure the Azure AD app proxy is the approach, but I'd need to do some tests and now I'm not working on this. I will update the thread if I do any progress.

Comment: I've given the app proxy a try. But there are still some hurdles to take. You might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30643760/181108) question as well. No answers yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a web site and you need something like Kerberos constrained delegation, see my blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2015/04/13/azure-ad-application-proxy-and-sharepoint-2013.aspx

If you need to connect over a specific protocol, such as TDS connections to SQL Server, then you can use Hybrid Connections.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2014/07/31/connect-sharepoint-online-to-an-on-premises-sql-server-from-an-azure-provider-hosted-app-using-hybrid-connections.aspx

If you need to use Kerberos Constrained Delegation to a non-HTTP protocol, see the following session where they demonstrate the few lines of code in .NET to read the incoming claims and impersonate the user.  Requires that you configure Kerberos Constrained Delegation as shown in the first article above.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/OFC-B327#fbid=

Comment: yeah, it's website (web API), that will get data from SQLServer and SP (using search rest api, for instance). How I have to configure security in the On premises WebAPI? When I call it from the Azure secure by AAD website, Can I use the same Bearer token?, and again in the on premises API, I need a new bearer token to call SP search API, or I can re-use the token coming from Azure AD?

Second link is fine if I want to hit SQL directly from Azure, but it's not the case.
Many thanks.